# How to plot mode as a line using Python, Numpy, Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

[Image here]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4XDG.png)I want to plot mode of as a line that comes from a bunch of lines. But I get value error as follows:
**ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 159) and (2, 1, 159)**

How to solve it?
My Code is as follows:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from scipy import stats

hvsra = []
for filename in glob('*.hv'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        hv = np.genfromtxt(f)

hv_m = np.ma.array(hv)
new_hv = hv_m[:,0:2]

freq = new_hv[:,0]
freq_new = np.reshape(freq_arr, (1, 159))

amp = new_hv[:,1] 
hvsra.append(amp)

hvsr = np.array(hvsra)
hvsrm = stats.mode(hvsr)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8)) 
plt.loglog(freq_new,
           hvsrm)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's a *"mode of as a line"* please? What's in a `.hv` file? Why do you glob all `.hv` files but only process one outside your loop? Is the totally uncommented code listing somehow related?

Comment: Hello @Mark, thanks for your attention. Now I have added a figure in the body of my question now, which contains a number of lines. I used take average of the lines, but now want to take mode or median instead!

But, I am not understanding the second part of your question. Could you clarify a bit more?